# PHP NumberFormatter setPattern Currency Sign

Tags: php, numberformatter

I have set the locale to `en` for my numberformatter. Formatting a currency as `USD` results in `$x.xx` whereas formatting a currency as `CAD` results in `CA$x.xx`. I have tried setting the pattern as both `¤#,##0.00` and `¤¤#,##0.00` but the first doesn't consistently add the letters before the currency symbol and the second doesn't do as I hoped. Can anyone suggest how to get both `US$x.xx` and `CA$x.xx` when formatting currencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
if(objNumberFormatter->getTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::CURRENCY_CODE) == 'USD')
    $objNumberFormatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::PAD_BEFORE_PREFIX, 'US');
```

OR

```
if($currency == 'USD')
    $objNumberFormatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::PAD_BEFORE_PREFIX, 'US');
```

Or you can change its pattern

```
if($currency == 'USD')
     $objNumberFormatter->setPattern('US ¤#,##0.00');
```